# Angular: Automatically accept self signed certificates

Tags: angular

does anyone know how to trust all the certificates (including the self signed ones) by using the Angular's HttpClient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refusing self-signed certificates is a security rule of the browser, to protect users, and has nothing to do with Angular. If you could do it programmatically, then it would make certificates pointless...
The users are the only responsible of manually trusting the certificate, if they want to.

Comment: I havent indicated if this is for a production release, and specifically in this case was for doing an integration test where it wasn't needed any kind of certificate trusting.

Comment: OK but the answer remains the same: the **browser** has to trust certificates on behalf of the user

Comment: a little late, but I think there's no 'browser' word on my original question #guerric-p

Comment: So you want to trust a certificate on the machine from the web page? That's even less possible